# How does GQUIC affect the WebRTC process?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, sdp, quic

I am making a simple WebRTC application for myself in order to understand the WebRTC process.

I am using the RTCPeerConnection object to generate an SDP and display it in my logs so I could see exactly what the SDP contains.

This was working fine on all popular browsers until the more recent Chrome update, which no longer displays the SDP.

I used wireshark to examine the packets and I can see that Chrome is using the GQUIC protocol, where other browsers use DNS and STUN protocols.

From this my questions are:

1. Is GQUIC preventing the SDP from being gnerated or from being displayed?
2. How, if at all, can I get the SDP to appear again in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No

It appears GQUIC is not the reason the update prevented the SDP from being created. GQUIC seems to be a protocol built on UDP to improve latency while allowing for the reliability of TCP, and I could find no reason for it to impact on the SDP business but rather it was a coincidence that I noticed this for the first time when the other problem occured.

2. Quick fix: change *WebRTC: Use Unified Plan SDP Semantics by default* to *disabled* in chrome:flags

The reason the SDP stopped working for me is that the new Chrome version has enabled *WebRTC: Use Unified Plan SDP Semantics by default*, since they appear to be moving from Plan-B to the Unified Plan which alters how the SDP is being passed. I am still trying to work out the exact difference this has on the SDP but in the meantime I was able to at least see the site working again when I change the flag so I know now that was the cause.